# Select query from edittext SQLite-Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

First Question:I created database on another activity called DatabaseHelper so this is another activity. I searched but couldn't understand but I believe that I am not connected to the database. How can I connect to database from an another activity ?

Second Question:I am trying to use Edittext to search database and receive multiple data(like productname and number) to another edittexts. My goal is to use barcode scanner device.It's functionalities are reading,writing and pressing enter key. So when device scans, cursor jumps into another edittext. To use function efficiently I want to search database when I press enter key. I have done this on C# but couldnt do it in Android,I am new to this. Can anyone help ?

**This is DatabaseHelper Class**

---

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Urunler.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "urunler_tablosu";
private static final String COL_2 = "UrunKodu";
private static final String COL_3 = "UrunAdi";
private static final String COL_4 = "Adet";             
private static final String COL_5 = "AlisFiyati";
private static final String COL_6 = "SatisFiyati";
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> YourList = new ArrayList<>();


DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (UrunKodu TEXT,UrunAdi TEXT,Adet REAL,AlisFiyati REAL,SatisFiyati REAL )");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS urunler_tablosu");
    onCreate(db);
}

//ÜRÜN KAYIT..

boolean insertData(String ukodu, String uadi, String adet, String afiyati, String sfiyati){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,ukodu);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,uadi);
    contentValues.put(COL_4,adet);
    contentValues.put(COL_5,afiyati);
    contentValues.put(COL_6,sfiyati);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    return result != -1;
}

//Get all item in your database
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllDatabaseData(String UrunKodu) { // we use the id to find it corresponding user details
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM '" + TABLE_NAME + "' WHERE UrunKodu='" + UrunKodu + "'",null);
    res.moveToFirst();
    while(!res.isAfterLast()){
        HashMap<String, String> array_list = new HashMap<>();
        array_list.put("Urunkodu",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COL_2)));
        array_list.put("UrunAdi",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COL_3)));
        array_list.put("Adet",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COL_4)));
        array_list.put("AlisFiyati",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COL_5)));
        array_list.put("SatisFiyati",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COL_6)));
        YourList.add(array_list);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return YourList;

}
```

}

---

Here is my search class called UrunKontrol

---

```
public class UrunKontrol extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String >>DataList = new ArrayList<>();
EditText editkontukodu,editkontuadi,editkontadet,editkontafiyati,editkontsfiyati;
Button arabuton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_urun_kontrol);

    editkontukodu = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kontrolbarkodno);
    editkontuadi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kontrolurunadi);
    editkontadet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kontrolurunadeti);
    editkontafiyati = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kontrolurunalisfiyati);
    editkontsfiyati = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kontrolurunsatisfiyati);
    arabuton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.aramabutonu);
    arabuton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DataList = new DatabaseHelper(UrunKontrol.this).getAllDatabaseData(UrunKodu); //I am getting error here on "UrunKodu"
            editkontuadi.setText(DataList.get(0).get("UrunAdi"));
            editkontadet.setText(DataList.get(0).get("Adet"));
            editkontafiyati.setText(DataList.get(0).get("AlisFiyati"));
            editkontsfiyati.setText(DataList.get(0).get("SatisFiyati"));
        }
    });

}
```

}

---

### Insert activity

```
public class Urunkayit extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editkayitbarkodno,editkontrolurunadi,editkontrolurunadeti,editkontrolurunalisfiyati,editkontrolurunsatisfiyati;
Button kaydetbuton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_urunkayit);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    editkayitbarkodno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kayitbarkodno);
    editkontrolurunadi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kayiturunadi);
    editkontrolurunadeti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kayiturunadeti);
    editkontrolurunalisfiyati = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kayiturunalisfiyati);
    editkontrolurunsatisfiyati = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.kayiturunsatisfiyati);
    kaydetbuton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.kayitbutonu);

    urunKaydetme();

}
public void urunKaydetme(){
    kaydetbuton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editkayitbarkodno.getText().toString(),
                            editkontrolurunadi.getText().toString(),
                            editkontrolurunadeti.getText().toString(),
                            editkontrolurunalisfiyati.getText().toString(),
                            editkontrolurunsatisfiyati.getText().toString());
                    if (isInserted = true){
                        Toast.makeText(Urunkayit.this,"Ürün Kaydedildi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        editkayitbarkodno.setText("");
                        editkontrolurunadi.setText("");
                        editkontrolurunadeti.setText("");
                        editkontrolurunalisfiyati.setText("");
                        editkontrolurunsatisfiyati.setText("");

                    }
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(Urunkayit.this,"Ürün Kaydedilemedi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

Comment: The way I see it, when you create your table you declare its field with; Number, BarcodeID, ProductName, Quantiy, Price but when  you search query you use the field UrunKodu which is  no where to find  in your declare fields

Comment: Uh sry I changed the parameters' name when I post here.This is my version of the code.I am declaring them with different names..UrunKodu=BarcodeID

Comment: can you post the new databasehelper class, retrieve activity and insert activity(you can remove the rest)